# UIWebView iOS - Capture hover or mousedown in HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, ios, ios7, uiwebview

How can I capture hover in HTML in UIWebView? I am not getting a callback to UIWebView delegates. My requirement is to block hover in UIWebView.

Please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: there will be no hover functionality in mobile device.

Comment: Attach `hover` events only in devices with mouse pointer, use css media queries to avoid `:hover` in touch devices.